# C++---- Comparing the the elements in the 2 arrays and displaying what are the values that are not similar

Tags: c++, visual-c++

*I need to:*

**1.** ask the user for the test answer and store in array, then compare the answer to the correct answer.
**2.** Takes the number of correct answers as a parameter, then Display the incorrectly and correctly answers that the user input. 
**3.** Display their the test result (passed or fail). 15/20 is the passing grade.

**4.** Only accept lowercase or uppercase A,B,C,D as an answer.

This is, so far, what I did. But I don't know how to compare the each of the elements/value of arrays and display the incorrectly answered and correctly answered questions. Also, how can I accept **only A,B,C,D** (whether the user input *either uppercase or lowercase,* **both,** --it should be acceptable) **letters** ?

**PLEASE HELP! your answers are highly appreciated :)**

```
 #include <iostream>
#include < iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

const int NUM_QUESTIONS = 20;
char correctAnsBig[NUM_QUESTIONS] = {   'B', 'D', 'A', 'A', 'C', 
                                    'A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'D',
                                    'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'D',
                                    'C', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'A'};

char correctAnsSmall[NUM_QUESTIONS] = { 'b', 'd', 'a', 'a', 'c',
                                    'a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'd',
                                    'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'd',
                                    'c', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'a' };
char ans[NUM_QUESTIONS];

bool ansEqual = true;
int count = 0;

void inputAnswers(char input[], int size)
{
   for (int cnt = 0; cnt < NUM_QUESTIONS; cnt++)
   {
       cout << "Enter your answer for #" << (cnt + 1) << " (A, B, C, or D): ";
       cin >> &ans[cnt];
   }

}

void checkAnswers()
{
   int count = 0;
   while (ansEqual && count < NUM_QUESTIONS)
   {
       if (ans[NUM_QUESTIONS] != correctAnsBig[NUM_QUESTIONS])
           ansEqual = false;
        count++;
   }

   if (ansEqual)
       cout << "Congratulations! You got it all right!\n";
   else
       cout << "You're a dumbass motherf*cker! A dishonor to your famiru!\n";
}

 void rightAns()
 {
    cout << "The correct answers are: \n";
    for (int cnt = 0; cnt < NUM_QUESTIONS; cnt++)
 {
       cout << (cnt + 1) << "." << "\t";
       cout << correctAnsBig[cnt] << endl;
 }
}

int main()
{

   inputAnswers(ans, NUM_QUESTIONS);
   rightAns();

   system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things that you need to understand:
- Array will be passed by reference, so you don't need &ans[cnt]
- User input could be lower or upper case. It does not matter. What matter is inside your function, how are you going to compare them. You can convert the user input into lower or upper before comparing.
- Try not to use global variables if not needed. In here, to keep track of the number of correct answer, you can do it with a local variable, just pass it to the function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

const int NUM_QUESTIONS = 20;
char correctAnsBig[NUM_QUESTIONS] = { 'B', 'D', 'A', 'A', 'C',
'A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'D',
'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'D',
'C', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'A' };

char ans[NUM_QUESTIONS];

// check for user input
bool ValidateInput(char input)
{
    input = toupper(input);
    return (input == 'A' || input == 'B' || input == 'C' || input == 'D');
}

void inputAnswers(char input[], int size)
{
    for (int cnt = 0; cnt < NUM_QUESTIONS; cnt++)
    {
        bool valid = false;

        do
        {
            cout << "Enter your answer for #" << (cnt + 1) << " (A, B, C, or D): ";
            cin >> ans[cnt];

            valid = ValidateInput(ans[cnt]);
        } while (!valid);       
    }
}

int checkAnswers()
{
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_QUESTIONS; i++)
    {
        // first, you need to convert all the character in the array to uppercase
        // then you will compare them
        // if they are equal, increase count of correct answer by 1
        // otherwise, do nothing
        if (toupper(ans[i]) == toupper(correctAnsBig[i]))
            count++;
    }
    return count;
}

void rightAns()
{
    cout << "The correct answers are: \n";
    for (int cnt = 0; cnt < NUM_QUESTIONS; cnt++)
    {
        cout << (cnt + 1) << "." << "\t";
        cout << correctAnsBig[cnt] << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int numOfCorrectAnswer = 0;

    inputAnswers(ans, NUM_QUESTIONS);
    rightAns();
    numOfCorrectAnswer = checkAnswers();

    cout << "You got " << numOfCorrectAnswer << " corrects" << endl;
    if (numOfCorrectAnswer == 20)
        cout << "You got it all right" << endl;
    else if (numOfCorrectAnswer > 15)
        cout << "You passed" << endl;
    else
        cout << "You failed" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the tips,it really helped and I will keep it in mind :) I tried it and every thing works fine! Except, I need to only accept the letters A, a, B,b, C,c, D, and d. If the user input an unacceptable char, I should output an error message. How should I do it?

Comment: Updated answer. Basically, if the user input is invalid, it will keep asking user before moving to the next question

Comment: I hope this is not much of a bother, but one last thing... I forgot that I also need to display the number of incorrect answers, how should I do it?

Comment: @Chrissy: you would need another array to hold the incorrect answer from the user. Lets just call it incorrectArr[]. So, in the checkAnswer(), on the if-else statement, you will check the user input with the correct answer. If it is correct, you increase count like normal. If it's not, you would add the incorrect answer to the incorrectArray[].

Answer (score 0):

Just use a canonical representation:

```
if (toupper(ans[count]) != correctAnsBig[count])
```

Comment: Thank you for your respond :) but that gave me error messages:

1. mismatch in formal parameter list
2. '[' : unable to resolve function overload

Comment: I just tried it in the function inputAnswers(), then I deleted the whole checkAnswers() function..and it worked! Thanks! <br>

However, I am required to have the checkAnswers() function and compare the user's input answers to the correct answers inside the function. But I'm not sure what codes should I put inside the checkAnswers() function to compare the arrays.

Comment: From those error messages it sounds like you were probably calling `checkAnswers()` with the wrong arguments.

Comment: I apologize, I forgot to include in the description that the codes that I posted works perfectly fine. However it is logically incorrect because I need to compare EACH elements/values of the array of the correct answers and the array where the user input their answers IN THE checkAnswers() function. 


Also, make sure that the user input only A, a, B,b, C,c, D, and d. NO other letters are acceptable

Comment: if you want to check the user input only in range A, a, B, b, C, c or D, d. Create a boolean function and compare the user input with all the values above. Return true if it matches, otherwise return false.